# How to set up data validation to allow only a date or a specific string on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to use Column Validation to ensure someone has entered a valid date, but I'd also like them to be able enter TBD - just those two options. Is this at all possible? Is there a custom formula I could enter into the Column validation in list setting?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using two columns and modifying the default view.  We can setup a list so that a user can enter a date or no date.  When we view the list (not editing), if the user entered a date then we will see the date.  If the user didn't enter a date then we will just see the text "TBD".

**Step 1: Create your columns**

- column 1: A non-required "Date Only" type DateTime field
- column 2: A calculated column using the following formula:

  =IF(column1="","TBD",TEXT(column1,"dd mm yyyy"))

In this formula, column1 is the name of your first DateTime column.  Also, the date format at the end of the validation can be changed to suit your regional requirements (for example, "mm dd yyy").

For column 2, also be sure to set the "data type returned from this formula" to be "Single line of text".

**Step 2: Modify your view of the list**

Once you have setup both columns, you should now modify the current default view by hiding column 1 from this view.  After you have done this, you will see that when viewing the list (not editing), only the calculated column will appear with either the entered date or "TBD".  However, when you go to edit the item, you will be able to enter a date using the built in calendar control, or simply leave blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below column validation for your single line of text field. Date is alphanumeric, it can be `12/10/2017` or `d5/df/2df3`

```
=IF(YourFieldName="TBD",TRUE,(AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("??/??/????",YourFieldName,1))),LEN(YourFieldName)=10)))
```